# Air travel back home UK to USA

Tags: uk, international-travel, layovers, airport-security

My wife and I (both US citizens) are flying from Leeds UK on British Airways, connecting in London Heathrow with an American Airlines flight to Philadelphia PA. What type of screening procedures will occur and will we be screened twice at the beginning in Leeds and at the connection in Heathrow? We have been given 1 hour and 40 minutes between flights to go from terminal 5 to terminal 3, which I understand is a 20-minute train ride. Our travel agent says these are the only possible flights. What will we possibly encounter in this situation?

Comment: If you have not actually booked it yet you could consider train from Leeds to London King's Cross, tube to Paddington, Heathrow Express to Heathrow. It may take longer but you can arrive at LHR almost whenever you choose.

Comment: The thing is if you book a single airline ticket with multiple flights and your first flight is delayed the airline covers you. If you travel by train and your trains are delayed such that you miss your flight then afacit you are screwed.

Answer (score 4):

If your travel agent has booked these as a single trip (ie checking your luggage straight through), putting a similar connection plan into the Heathrow [connection planner](https://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections) indicates that you can actually travel between terminals on a dedicated connections shuttle bus (note: the train journey does not actually take 20 minutes, but it isn't that frequent so travel time PLUS wait time can be up to 20 minutes). Once you get to terminal 3 you **will** reclear security.

The minimum connection time listed for T5 to T3 is 90 minutes, so you may not have time to dawdle but it's a valid connection so if indeed you have a through ticket the airline has to assist you if there are delays.